# Why can quantum-classical ensembles be written as $\sigma = \sum_x |x\rangle\!\langle x|\otimes{\rm Tr}_{A}((M^x_A \otimes I_B) \rho_{AB} )$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, quantum-measurements

I was reading about the entropic uncertainty principle, but there is something that is confusing me.

Suppose we have a state $\rho_{AB}$ for a state that belongs to the product of
two Hilbert spaces, that we can identify as Alice's part of the system and the Bob one's.

Now, supposing Alice performs a measurement with operators $M^x_A$, and before she tells Bob about it, we can model the situation with a register composed only by orthonormal distinguishable states.

So building the post measurement state, I imagine something like
$$
\sigma = \sum_x p(x) |x\rangle \langle x | \otimes Tr_{A}((M^x_A \otimes I_B) \rho_{AB} ) \, ,
$$
with $p(x)$ the probability that the result $x$ occurred.

Instead the author writes
$$
\sigma = \sum_x  |x\rangle \langle x |\otimes Tr_{A}((M^x_A \otimes I_B) \rho_{AB} ) \, ,
$$
without accounting for measurement probabilities.

What am I missing?

P.s. the book is "From classical to quantum Shannon theory" by Wilde.

Comment: Well, what is the post measurement state... and what is $p(x)$? If you do everything carefuly, it should work out fine. Also you should add the reference.

Comment: I don't understant why are we not considering the probabilities

Comment: Yes. Again: What is the post-measurement state?!

Comment: I think $\sigma = \sum_x( M_A^{x} \otimes I_B )^{\dagger} (M_A^{x} \otimes I_B) \rho_{AB}$?

Comment: Is this properly normalized?

Comment: ... alternatively, write out what p{x} is and rethink.

Comment: The probabilities are implicitly encoded in $\rho_{AB}$ and are extracted automatically upon applying $M^x_A$ and taking the partial trace over $A$. The representation of measurements as a linear map are like $\rho \mapsto p_a \rho_a$ for some outcome $a$, and **not** like $\rho \mapsto \rho_a$, which would be nonlinear since $\rho_a = P_a \rho P_a / \text{tr} (P_a \rho)$ with $p_a = \text{tr} ( P_a \rho)$. So the probability is implicit in what you wrote.